# Power BI: Finding earliest price per category

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have a table in PBI where I have three columns: Category, Price, and Date.

I want to create a measurement that shows the earliest price per category, no matter what filters are set on the Date column.

For example, my table looks like this:

| Category | Price | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 2022-01-01 |
| A | 15 | 2022-02-01 |
| A | 12 | 2022-03-01 |
| B | 20 | 2022-01-01 |
| B | 15 | 2022-02-01 |
| B | 12 | 2022-03-01 |

And when I add my measurement to the table, it should look like:

| Category | Price | Date | Earliest Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 2022-01-01 | 10 |
| A | 15 | 2022-02-01 | 10 |
| A | 12 | 2022-03-01 | 10 |
| B | 20 | 2022-01-01 | 20 |
| B | 15 | 2022-02-01 | 20 |
| B | 12 | 2022-03-01 | 20 |

I have tried using this measurement, but can't get it to work:

```
Earliest price = 
CALCULATE(
   SUM('Table'[Price]),
   'Table'[Date] = MIN('Table'[Date]),
   ALL('Table'[Date])
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Earliest = 
VAR x = CALCULATE(MIN('Table'[Date]), ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[Category]))
RETURN 
CALCULATE(MIN('Table'[Price]),  ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[Category]), 'Table'[Date] = x)
```

OR

```
Earliest = 
CALCULATE(
    FIRSTNONBLANKVALUE('Table'[Date], MAX('Table'[Price])), 
    ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Category])
    )
```

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for the reply! I've ran into some other issues when using the date column as a key to a calendar table and when I use dates from the calendar table the measurement doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Can you ask a new question with all the problem details and someone or myself can take a look.